# Find Volume of Sphere w/ Radius of Spherical Cap

Tags: spheres

I'm trying to create a sphere around one known dimension - the radius of what would be a spherical cap.  The spherical cap would have a volume equal to one-third the volume of the whole sphere.

radius of spherical cap, r=692.820323

Comment: Can you use integrals?

Comment: I am aware that this would be the key, however, I myself am ignorant with executing integrals.  If someone can walk me through it, that would be great!

Comment: I am rusty in multivariable calculus, but I think I can figure something out. First, please clarify: The $r$ you have is the radius of the sphere? Or $r$ is the radius of the cap, if you are measuring from the flat/bottom part of the cap's center to an edge?

Comment: My r is the radius of the cap.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: integrate along the radius of the sphere (the area).